# Inserting double quotations into a CSV file

Tags: csv, double-quotes

I download a report from SSRS to a CSV file but there are no double-quotations around each value. My columns contain Numbers, text and general formats.
In the CSV file, I have tried concatenating the double quotes but then when I open it with Notepad++, it shows 3 lots of double-quotes and when I take the double quotes off, it shows no quotes. What do I do?

I need to eventually upload the CSV into a piece of software, which will only work if I have a single Double-quotation around each cell but have been struggling all morning to get this in the right format

I have concatenated each cell so that the cell shows double-quotes around each cell value but when opening up in Notepad, it shows 3 double quotes before and after the cell value.

I have tried to convert all cells as text before doing the above and still no joy

Comment: Why do you need double quotes? You need only if in example you have a comma inside a cell value

Comment: When I download my report from SSRS or BI Query, it puts everything in one column separated by comma's. I then need to use Text to Columns to separate it and although I save as a CSV, it doesn't add the double quotations on each cell

Comment: Could you share some sample rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it. Instead of using Notepad++, I used the ordinary notepad.

I had to concatenate every cell with double quotes, save and close the CSV. I then opened it up as a Notepad doc but it showed triple quotes around each value but a quick "find & replace" sorted it out.

You can save NotePad as CSV but you cannot with NotePad++

Answer (score 0):

You can convert through MS Access, export as CSV and choose your options to get the quotes